# How do I update the list when I add an item?

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I am trying to update the list to reflect the new item when it is added. Currently, it isn't showing once I press the "paperplane" button. I have left out the repeating blocks of code if you see the references.

I have a suspicion that the problem comes in the button from MergedView but couldn't find a solution. It compiles but doesn't execute the intended action.

```
import Foundation

class One: Identifiable, ObservableObject { // ObservableObject requires class

    let id: UUID
    var item: String = ""
    @Published var completed: Bool = false // this will affect the UI

    init(item: String, completed: Bool) {
        id = UUID()
        self.item = item
        self.completed = completed
    }

    }

    class OneList: ObservableObject {
        @Published var items = [One(item:"",completed:false)]
    }




    struct VitalRow: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var item: One
        var body: some View {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: item.completed ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                Text(item.item)
            }
        }
    }

    struct ButtonView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var itemss1: OneList
    @EnvironmentObject var itemss2: TwoList
    @EnvironmentObject var itemss3: ThreeList
    @EnvironmentObject var itemss4: FourList

    @State private var  showingAdditem: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()

            HStack{
                Spacer()

                Button(action:{
                    self.showingAdditem = true
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .font(Font.system(size: 25,weight: .regular))
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .frame( width: 50, height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }.sheet(isPresented: $showingAdditem)
                {
                    MergedView()
                        .environmentObject(OneList())
                        .environmentObject(TwoList())
                        .environmentObject(ThreeList())
                        .environmentObject(FourList())
                    //items1: self.itemss1, items2: self.itemss2, items3: self.itemss3, items4: self.itemss4)
                }.background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 3,
                            x: 3,
                            y: 3)
                    .padding()
                    .offset(x: -5,
                            y: 15)
            }
        }
    }
}


    struct MergedView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var items1: OneList
    @EnvironmentObject var items2: TwoList
    @EnvironmentObject var items3: ThreeList
    @EnvironmentObject var items4: FourList

    /*@ObservedObject var items1: OneList
    @ObservedObject var items2: TwoList
    @ObservedObject var items3: ThreeList
    @ObservedObject var items4: FourList*/

    @State private var item =  ""

    @State var blockcolor1 = Color.red.opacity(0.90)
    @State var blockcolor2 = Color.red.opacity(0.70)
    @State var blockcolor3 = Color.red.opacity(0.45)
    @State var blockcolor4 = Color.red.opacity(0.20)

    @State var itemvalue: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack{
                NavigationView{
                    HStack{
                        TextField("Item", text: self.$item)
                            .padding()
                        Button(action:{

                            if self.itemvalue == 1{
                                let things1 = One(item: self.item, completed: false)
                                self.items1.items.append(things1)
                                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            }
                      {
                            Image(systemName:"paperplane")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .padding()
                        }
          HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(self.blockcolor1)
                                    //.fill(Color.red.opacity(0.90))
                                    //.frame(width: 140,height: 180)
                                    .frame(width: geo.size.width/3, height: geo.size.height/4.6)
                                    .cornerRadius(15)
                                    .shadow(radius: 6)
                                    .onTapGesture{
                                        self.blockcolor1 = Color.red.opacity(0.1)
                                        self.itemvalue = 1
                                }




    struct CheckboxList: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var item1List: OneList
    @EnvironmentObject var item2List: TwoList
    @EnvironmentObject var item3List: ThreeList
    @EnvironmentObject var item4List: FourList

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Vital")) {
                    ForEach(item1List.items.indices) { index in
                        VitalRow()
                            .environmentObject(self.item1List.items[index])
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.item1List.items[index].completed.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't paste the entire code, just create a small prototype with bare minimum code to replicate the issue then post that minimum code, so that it is easier for others to understand the problem. That will help you identify the problem as well

Comment: Why are you `.environmentObject(OneList())` inside the body of the view. You have done it twice in your code, don't initialise the `environmentObject` inside the body of the view because the `body` gets executed multiple times. Please post smaller cleaner examples that compile and are formatted properly.